# Is there a way to return both a redirection and response code at the end of a submission

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I'm not exactly sure if this the correct way to implement it, but my idea was to give a redirection to a successful (or unsuccessful) submission with a response code.

Let's say in this situation we are doing an update to an existing blog post.

First, we'll check if the record exist? Ideally, I would like to stay on the current page (w/ a response code) if it doesn't.

```
$blogpost = Blogpost::find($id);
if(is_null($blogpost)){
    return response()->json(["message"=>"Record Not Found!"], 404);
}
```

Secondly, I would do a validation check to see if everything is okay. To which we would also like to stay on the current page (w/ a response code) if it's not correct.

```
$valid=['title' => 'required|min:3',
        'msg'=>'required|min:3',
];

$valida = Validator::make($request->all(), $valid);
if($valida->fails()){return response()->json($valida->errors(), 400);}
```

Lastly, when all goes I would like to have a redirection (with a 200 response code).

```
$blogpost->update($request->all());
return redirect('/blogposts')->with('success', 'Post Has Been Updated!');
```

But the goal is to have both a redirection with a response code.
So, what I thought of doing was the following which isn't correct I think.

```
return redirect('/blogposts')->with(response()->json($blogpost, 200));
```

Hopefully, someone could provide me with some guidance thank you in advance!

Comment: Redirect is a response usually with code 301 or 302

Answer (score 0):

How I implement this (for 302 especially) is like this:

```
return response(json(["message"=>"Record Not Found!"]), 404);
```

which only make sense if you access $this controller action through an AJAX request.
Further:

```
if($valida->fails()){return response(json($valida->errors()), 400);}
```

But redirecting with a json response the way you would like it won't work. It's a URL (Route) you are redirecting to. You could capture the data with `?id=1` etc, resulting in 'ugly' URLs. Unless your route is set to `Route::get('blogposts/id?')->...`

```
return redirect()->to('/blogposts', 200)->with('id', $blogpost->id);
```

Comment: my route is actually set to 
`
Route::put('blogpost/{id}', 'BlogPostController@update');
`

in that case, would the following work?
`
return redirect()->to('blogpost/{id}', 200);
`